# En una app cordova o ionic cargar una web externa pero navegar entre paginas con enlaces en un menu de aplicación en la app

Tags: ionic, cordova

Si usamos el plugin de cordova InAppBrowser para mostrar en la app URL externas (una web wordpress) como contenido central de nuestra app,

¿Existe algún plugin de cordova que pudiese presentar una barra de menú al estilo nativo de dispositivo, siempre visible sobre el cordova InAppBrowser para cargar diferentes urls en el cordova InAppBrowser según el usuario interactúa con este menú.

Básicamente deseamos poder cambiar los enlaces en el InAppBrowser desde una barra de menú independiente en la app. Usar Cordova o Ionic.

No se me ocurre otra forma de preguntar esto, estamos un poco perdidos, es una propuesta que nos ha hecho un cliente.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Edito la pregunta?

Comment: He intentando en lo posible resumirlo en una duda, tenemos experiencia en cordova pero esta forma de aplicar cordova no la conocemos, la pregunta original quedó amplia debido a esto, disculpen. Se admiten todo tipo de ideas

Comment: Hola has realizado varias preguntas con el mismo formato, veo que aun no has leido [ask], te sugiero revisarlo para crear preguntas en el sitio, saludos.